# Split real and imag parts of function with derivative

Tags: complex

Consider a complex function `y` with a **real** argument `x` and the function `y` itself is an argument of another function `f`, which takes the 2nd-derivative of `y` with respect to `x`

```
f[y_] := y''[x]
```

It seems that `ComplexExpand` gives the right answer

```
ComplexExpand[f[yr + I*yi]]

(*((I yi + yr)^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x]*)
```

Well, when I try to extract its real and imaginary parts separately, the following approaches failed.

```
ComplexExpand[Re@f[yr + I*yi]]
(*((I yi + yr)^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x]*)

Re@ComplexExpand[f[yr + I*yi]]

(*Re[((I yi + yr)^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x]]*)

ComplexExpand[f[yr + I*yi]] // Re

(*Re[((I yi + yr)^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x]]*)
```

I expect to obtain something like `yr''[x]` and `yi''[x]` for the real and imaginary parts.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: First line is: "f with a real argument". But then 4th line shows f taking yr + I yi. Please elaborate.

Comment: Note also that your first `ComplexExpand` expression accomplishes nothing: `f[yr + I*yi] == ComplexExpand[f[yr + I*yi]]`.

Comment: @PaulCommentary sorry, I was so careless. I meant `y` has a real argument `x`, and another function `f` takes derivative of `y` w.r.t. `x`. Please see my update.

Comment: @MarcoB Ha... I just want to take the derivative of `y[x]=yr[x]+i*yi[x]` w.r.t. $x \in R$ and get `y'[x]=yr'[x]+i*yi'[x]` for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to tell Mathematica what symbols are functions, by explicitly stating them with an argument. Say you have a "function" $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and you try

```
D[f, x]
(* 0 *)
```

Since Mathematica does not know that `f` is a "function". However, the following gives the desired output

```
D[f[x], x]
(* f'[x] *)
```

For your problem my recommended way to go would be via pure functions, e.g.

```
ClearAll[f]
f[y_, x_] := y''[x]
f[Function[{x}, yr[x] + I yi[x]], x]
(* I (yi^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x] + (yr^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x] *)
```

instead of `Function` you could also use the lambda-style syntax where the arguments are denoted by `Slot`s (`#`) and the function is finalized by a `&`, e.g.

```
#^2&[x] == Function[{x}, x^2][x]
(* True *)
```